# Inherit from tableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, inheritance, tableview

I have MyVC that Inherited from tableViewController.

Now I Inherit from MyVC in DetailVC.

I want to have tableView in MyVC and cell in DetailVC. (I have difficult cell construction)
Now I have full implementation of MyVC in DetailVC(with MyVC's navigation buttons).

How can I have table with one cell in  DetailVC?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model containing cell components like name,Occupation etc. Store all the data from populating the table cells in array. 
In

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method

```
self.timeSheetModel = [self.timeSheetListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

self.detailVC = [[DetailVC alloc]init];

//Create a property model in your detailVC assign it.

self.detailVC.model = [self.timeSheetListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Pass the model . You will get the data in your detailVC of the selected cell.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailVC animated:YES];

}
```

In your detailVC you can access the values directly

```
self.myNameLabel.text  = self.model.name;
```